# Open Access Form in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a Problem with my code. I have a Excel sheet and i want to open a Access Form with VBA. But im getting this error "Runtime Error 429 - Cannot Create Active-X Component"

```
Sub opp()

Dim Access As Object
Set Access = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Access.Visible = True
Access.OpenCurrentDatabase "U:\Database1.accdb"
MsgBox "Datenbank geöffnet."
Access.CloseCurrentDatabase
Set Access = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? Which version of Office is installed?

Comment: This Line -> Set Access = CreateObject("Access.Application"). Im using Office 2010.

Comment: Did you check that Microsoft Access really is installed on your System and that you can start it by hand? If so, it seems to be a problem with that installation. You could try to let the setup routine repair it.

Comment: Access is installed and i can start it.